# How do I add custom syntax highlighting and autocompletion for a DSL made with PeggyJS?

Tags: javascript, dsl, codemirror, peg

I have created a DSL using PeggyJS to create my parser. Now I would like to have a programming environment with custom syntax highlighting and autocompletion. What is best practice to do this?

I have looked in to CodeMirror or using VS code, but I'm not sure what the best way forward is. I would prefer the programming environment to be web-based.